# Paradoxical Javascript Variable Defining

Tags: javascript, math, undefined

I am trying to calculate a maths question. It requires the use of variables within variables that loop around.

Here is my JavaScript Code:

```
var a = m+1;
var b = n+1;
var c = o+1;
var d = p+1;
var e = q+1;
var f = r+1;
var g = s+1;
var h = t+1;
var i = u+1;
var j = v+1;
var l = w+1;

var m = (1+b)/2;
var n = (a+c)/2;
var o = (b+d)/2;
var p = (c+e)/2;
var q = (d+f)/2;
var r = (e+g)/2;
var s = (f+h)/2;
var t = (g+i)/2;
var u = (h+j)/2;
var v = (i+l)/2;
var w = (j+12)/2;

function CalculateA() {
    alert(a);
}
```

The HTML is just a button calling CalculateA() Function.

This results with undefined. Is there a way to properly calculate this or is it not possible with javascript or coding.

*Edit*
I relize now that this isn't working very well.
Also I ran it through excel with looping calculations and found the answer.
Thanks for all your help anyway.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9I2lCue4HpLZEh3X0NGTUE4YXM
The Excel Calculation ^

Comment: Are you sure that's the proper way to define those variables? It looks like `a` depends on `m` which depends on `b` which depends on `n` which depends on `a`.

Comment: `m` is not defined at the time the line `var a = m + 1` is executed.

Comment: all vars are declared in advance through hoisting, but the value is then `undefined`.

Comment: This needs to be replaced with one or more methods

Comment: Actually, are you trying to solve a set of equations just by writing them down? I don't think that will ever work.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive? Do you expect JavaScript to treat this as a system of equations and solve for a?

Comment: What is the exact math problem you are solving?

Comment: Yes, I relize that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give all variables a start value of zero to prevent [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) and then call the operations again until `a` is converging to `12.916666666666651`.

```js
function calc() {
    a = m + 1;
    b = n + 1;
    c = o + 1;
    d = p + 1;
    e = q + 1;
    f = r + 1;
    g = s + 1;
    h = t + 1;
    i = u + 1;
    j = v + 1;
    l = w + 1;
    m = (1 + b) / 2;
    n = (a + c) / 2;
    o = (b + d) / 2;
    p = (c + e) / 2;
    q = (d + f) / 2;
    r = (e + g) / 2;
    s = (f + h) / 2;
    t = (g + i) / 2;
    u = (h + j) / 2;
    v = (i + l) / 2;
    w = (j + 12) / 2;
    console.log(a);
}

var a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0, g = 0, h = 0, i = 0, j = 0, l = 0, m = 0, n = 0, o = 0, p = 0, q = 0, r = 0, s = 0, t = 0, u = 0, v = 0, w = 0,
    ii, letter;

for (ii = 0; ii < 1000; ii++) {
    calc();
}

for (ii = 1; ii <= 23; ii++) {
    letter = (ii + 9).toString(36);
    letter === 'k' || console.log(letter, window[letter]); // k is missing ...
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is impossible in coding. it is returning undefined because 'a' is declared on top where m is not defined and it is "NaN" error -- Not a Number.

Answer (score -1):

The variables end up depending onto each other, which means that your result will always be NaN.

Javascript tries to give you an exact result for the formula, which it can't. What you need for this math issue, is to replace the variables in each term with each other, to get to a result with only 1 variable - I don't think there's a way for you to do that in Javascript with less effort than doing it manually.